# Is this splice definition Correct?

Tags: angularjs, array-splice

Hello just asking is this AngularJS splice definition is correct, if not, what is the correct form of use

```
$scope.user=[]; 
$scope.userfakemodi={};

$scope.user.splice(indexuser,0,$scope.userfakemodi);
```

> Imagine that I have any data in the arrays

Thanks

Comment: $scope.user.splice(indexuser, 1); is the right syntax of your problem. In this case one user remove from $scope.user

Comment: you can get all the info on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp. On SO, its encouraged to put questions which is something that you can't find on google easily. Also, you need to provide what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The above syntax is correct.

$scope.user.splice(indexuser,0,$scope.userfakemodi);